# Jmeter 5.1.1 - Performance Metrics appears different in Jmeter's in-built Listener and Html Dashboard Report

Tags: jmeter, dashboard, jmeter-5.0

Here is the snapshot of the Jmeter's in-built Listener
[image]

And this is the snapshot of Html Dashboard Report of the same **.jtl** result
[image]

Here all the mterics are different except the **Min** value

Can anyone please help here, what I'm missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [JMeter Changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

> - [Bug 58653](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58653) - New JMeter Dashboard/Report with Dynamic Graphs, Tables to help analyzing load test results. Developed by Ubik-Ingenierie and contributed by Decathlon S.A. and Ubik-Ingenierie / UbikLoadPack

Most probably these guys from Ubik-Ingenierie are not very good at counting Sample Results especially when it comes to tests which have [Transaction Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)

[image]

In order to get consistent results I would suggest using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv result.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

as the result you will get a CSV form of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener having the statistics you're looking for

[image]

You can install [JMeter Plugins Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) and [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. Yes, it does considers only the requests processed in Html Report whereas the Transactions are also do counted in in-built Listeners.